# Dynamic Footprint in Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

i want to ask if someone has an idea of how to make my footprint dynamic depending on the speed. So for example, if the robot is traveling with high speed, the footprint size should increase and vice versa. In my configuration files for navigation i am using DWA (same as the turtlebot config files), but it would be really nice to control the footprint dynamically.

Any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237365/dynamic-footprint-in-navigation/) by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the documentation for the [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Component_API) they mention that there is a subscription to the `footprint` topic. This led me to believe that you ought to be able to publish on one of the `<costmap>/footprint` and have everything be automatically updated. A quick test shows that this does appear to be the case (although I haven't thoroughly tested). In the [source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L137-L138) you can see they do indeed subscribe to the topic, and that the subscribed footprint eventually [changes the local attribute](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L337-L344), and further, this eventually is [published](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L414-L437) back to the topic.

Additionally, note that in the [Trajectory scoring parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner#Trajectory_Scoring_Parameters) of dwa_local_planner, they mention that there is a parameter to scale the size of the footprint based on how fast the robot is going. The actual implementation of this (which is easier to understand than the docs) is [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/base_local_planner/src/obstacle_cost_function.cpp#L102-L114). This may also fit your use case.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2